# Running Visual Studio 2008 C# (MSTest.exe based) unit tests in Mono

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mono, mstest

I'm using VS2008 to develop a project that I'm starting to test under Mono.
There are a number of unit tests written using the VS unit test framework, is there a tool that will let me run these in Mono?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the features that you're using it can be trivial or hard. You can use namespace/type aliasing to use another class library to do asserts, and the attributes. I've written console programs that run the tests manually - but of course I had access to the vs namespaces and assemblies.

For mono - my suggestion would be to use another testing system altogether as doing it yourself with system.reflection namepace to load the assembly,  reflect the attributes and execute as you need to, will be tedious.

For example:

```
Pseudo code:

var assembly = loadAsembly(....)
foreach(type in assembly.types) {
 if(type is static class and had method with AssemblyInitialiseAttrubute)){
    InvokeTheMethod(method);
 }
}

foreach(type in assembly.types) {
 if(type is not class and had method with TestClass)){
    InvokeTheMethod(method);
 }
 foreach(method in type with ClassinitialiseAttribute)
}
... etc
```

Comment: Yes, thought I might end up rolling my own, but am still holding out for a readymade solution. Thanks.

Comment: That turned out to be fairly straightforward, although I currently have a reference to the VS unit test assembly which defines the attributes (which I copy over to Mono, not very kosher.)

Comment: why not define you're own attributes? then you get the best  of both worlds?

Comment: you can make your reference disappear using the msbuild conditional attribute in the itemgroup entry for the reference in question - Condition='"$(am_using_mono)" != ""' - then in mono define the environment variable am_using_mono

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code and it works well on Mono. The code does NOT have any dependence on the Visual Studio test duite DLL. Surprisingly, it runs a little faster on Mone (running on VirtualBox on my PC) than in Visual Studio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace drvrapp {
    public class TestRunner {
        // assembly file (e.g. MyTestAssembly.dll) which should be in the same directory 
        public static void TestDll(string assemblyFile) {
            string symbolsFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assemblyFile) + ".pdb";

            byte[] assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyFile);
            byte[] symbolsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(symbolsFile);

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes, symbolsBytes);

            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
                if (HasAttribute(type, "TestClass"))
                    foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods())
                        if (HasAttribute(method, "TestMethod"))
                            RunTest(method);
        }

        private static void RunTest(MethodInfo method) {
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("Running {0}.{1}...", method.DeclaringType.Name, method.Name);

            if (HasAttribute(method, "Ignore")) {
                Console.WriteLine("IGNORED");
                return;
            }

            try {
                Type testType = method.DeclaringType;
                object typeClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(testType);

                RunInitializeOrCleanup(typeClassInstance, "TestInitialize");
                method.Invoke(typeClassInstance, null);
                RunInitializeOrCleanup(typeClassInstance, "TestCleanup");

                Console.WriteLine("PASSED");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        private static void RunInitializeOrCleanup(object instance, string attribute) {
            MethodInfo method = instance.GetType().GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(x => HasAttribute(x, attribute));
            if (method != null)
                method.Invoke(instance, null);
        }

        private static bool HasAttribute(MemberInfo info, string attributeName) {
            return info.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(x => x.GetType().Name == attributeName + "Attribute");
        }
    }
}
```