# What are the differences between Microsoft TestTools' UnitTesting and NUnit?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mono

I use `NUnit` for Mono/C# on my Mac, but I need to use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` for unit testing.

- How is Microsoft TestTools' UnitTesting different from NUnit? Can I just change the namespace and recompile to get the same result, or do I have to rewrite the test?
- Can I copy some of the assemblies to my Mac to run tests for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`? If so, what files should be copied?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUnit vs Visual Studio 2010's MSTest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367734/nunit-vs-visual-studio-2010s-mstest)

Comment: This one may help you: [Running Visual Studio 2008 C# (MSTest.exe based) unit tests in Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249887/running-visual-studio-2008-c-mstest-exe-based-unit-tests-in-mono).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Migrating from NUnit to MSTest](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/31/migrating-from-nunit-to-mstest.aspx).

As to why you might try convincing your team to migrate the other way, see [NUnit vs. MsTest: NUnit wins for Unit Testing](//osherove.com/blog/2010/3/5/nunit-vs-mstest-nunit-wins-for-unit-testing.html).

Answer (score 4):

Ask yourself - why do you need the Ms tools if you already have a working set with NUnit.

Personally I've worked with both and unless working in legacy where the MS tool was in great use, I'd choose NUnit for this toolset due to the larger community support I get in cases of problems.

Comment: If possible, I'll keep using NUnit. I need to use MS tools as the other team members are using it, and I'm the only one who uses Mac/Mono. I need to write test for them to run on PC.

Comment: Just to be clear. NUnit runs on Windows too. Its all sitting on top of the .NET Framework. MsTest is just another framework sitting on top of the .NET stack. Consistency is good, but there is also no reason you couldn't run both testing frameworks if needed.

Answer (score 1):

MSTest can be used without installing Visual Studio. You will need to install Visual Studio Test Agent, which is a free download from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1334.

I think this approach is better from a licensing perspective than manually copying MSTest.exe and its dependencies onto the build server.

Answer (score -1):

My biggest problem with MSTest is that it requires the install of Visual Studio, even if you are trying to run a lean build server.

NUnit can install and run anywhere.

Comment: This is not generally true. We have MSTest versions 2015 and 2017, installed from the Visual Studio Test Agent on a Windows slave, and that works fine. See answer by @SambodhanDhammapathee